# x ray scraper crawl to another page not returning data

Tags: node.js, cheerio, x-ray

hi am testing the new x ray web scraping , following the listed tutorial for crawling to another website , does not return anything 
[github x-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray)

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('http://google.com', {
   main: 'title',
   image: x('#gbar a@href', 'title'), // follow link to google images
})(function(err, obj) {
/*
   {
     main: 'Google',
     image: 'Google Images'
    }
*/
})
```

does  not work , besides this is my code ,for the same logic

```
    var html='http://www.myjoyonline.com/news.php';
    x(html,'ul.opinion-listings li' ,[{
       title : '.head .title a',
       desc : '.info',
       date : '.head',
       img :'.image-inner a img@src',
       url :'.head .title a@href',
       fullStory : x('.head .title a@href', 'title'),
   }])(function(err, obj) {
       console.log(obj);
   });
```